# scanf not working. need to read double from console

Tags: c, io, scanf

I'm  not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I'm not able to read a double from the console. Reading an it works fine for some reason. I'm using Xcode.

```
double n1;

// get input from the user
printf("Enter first number: ");
scanf("%f", &n1);

printf("%f", n1);
```

This will always print 0 no matter what I enter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable of type double not working when read by scanf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285056/variable-of-type-double-not-working-when-read-by-scanf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%f` is looking for a float, not a double. If you want to use a double, use the format `%lf`.

As a somewhat interesting aside, clang warns about this without any extra flags, gcc 4.6 won't warn about it even with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: Fortunately GCC 5.2.1-22ubuntu2 complains without any arguments

Answer (score 5):

`%f` is meant for a `single precision floating-point value` (float). The format specifier you need is `%lf`, meaning `long precision floating-point value` (double).

Answer (score 2):

Its all about how data is stored in memory. 
Let me first tell that how long and float are stored in memory.

- A double (long float, 64 bits) is stored in memory like or [this](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_uIwyaTjqYYw/SmTy9s3LV6I/AAAAAAAAA-o/wtA80CFDWfM/s640/61.jpeg) (little endian notation).
- Where as a float (32 bits) is stored like [this](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_uIwyaTjqYYw/SmTy9ZLEwkI/AAAAAAAAA-g/vHHpK6AzZaU/s640/60.jpeg) (little endian notation). 
  Also have a look at this "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Internal_representation" (all floating data types)

So here you are asking to take input as `%f` (i.e. float, which is 4 bytes but double is 8 bytes), so compiler takes input from console and converts it to float type and stores it at memory location(which is actually 8 bytes) of variable (here `n1`).

Comment: little endian and big endian   http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/endian.html