# Scanf for double not working in Dev C++

Tags: c, printf, double, scanf

I am having problem with floating point numbers. I think something is clashing here.

The output is :

[image: Screenshot of the output]

My code :

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){


    double y;

    printf("enter a decimal number: ");
    scanf("%f", &y);

    printf("%f\n", y);

    fflush(stdin);

    getchar();
    return 0;

    }
```

I am using Dev C++ 4.9.9.2 and first of all, I have to flush the carriage return out several times if it's not read previously . So if there is any alternative there then tell me. And secondly the output is giving this...

Comment: Don't use ancient IDEs (Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2 is from 2005) and don't use `fflush(stdin)` (it doesn't do what you think it does)

Comment: so what will i use instead of dev C++ and `fflush(stdin)` ?

Comment: If you don't want other IDEs, there is at least a newer version of Dev-C++ (Orwell Dev-C++), which is actually maintained.

Comment: Thanks but will this type of problem arise over there?

Comment: Why do you use a picture instead of simply pasting the text?

Comment: unable to copy the exact output. couldn't select. that's why.

Comment: so you should also ask about how to select and do copy pasting from cmd of windows..my friend.. @nick

Comment: @SUMITKUMARSINGHDIXIT yes, maybe in another question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scanf not working. need to read double from console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860615/scanf-not-working-need-to-read-double-from-console)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
scanf("%lf", &y);
```

instead. Since `scanf("%f", &y);` works for `float`s only.

If you enable compiler warnings it would tell you that the format specifier `"%f"` expects a `float *` and not `double *` argument.

Comment: thanks but what will I do if the carriage return is not read earlier. as I mentioned the problem.?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, `scanf` will ignore all whitespace characters and hence it will block until input has non whitespace characters.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` has undefined behavior too.

Answer (score 2):

Using wrong format specifier invoke [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and that's why you are getting unexpected result. Once UB is invoked, you may either get expected or unexpected result. Nothing can be said.
Use `%lf` to read `double` type data.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong format specifier in the `scanf` and doing this will result in [UB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)(Undefined Behaviour).The correct format specifier for a `double` is `%lf` while that of a float is `%f`. So Just change your `scanf` to

```
scanf("%lf",&y);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
scanf("%lf", &y);
```