# Scanf not reading in double

Tags: c, floating-point, double, scanf

I am trying to read in a `double` value continuously from the user  using `scanf`.

Code:

```
printf("Enter A value: \n");
double input;
int result = scanf("%f", &input);
printf("INPUT: %f\n", input);
```

The output is

```
INPUT: 0.000
```

Comment: why is result int and not double ?

Comment: @user3121023 I was only curious  to know the intention of OP by doing that. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanf for double not working in Dev C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657977/scanf-for-double-not-working-in-dev-c)

Comment: [Problems with scanf and doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19890748/995714)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You lied to the compiler: when scanning, `%f` says you supply a pointer to `float`. But you provided a pointer to `double`.

To fix, either use `%lf` **or** declare `input` as `float`.

Note that there is an asymmetry with `printf` formats, which uses `%f` for both `float` and `double` arguments. This works because `printf` arguments are promoted to `double` (and are not pointers).

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to read in a double value **continuously** from the user using scanf.

To do so you need a loop, like the following:

```
while(scanf("%lf", &input) == 1) {
    //code goes here...
    printf("INPUT: %lf\n", input);
    //code goes here...
}
```

Note that, as the primitive type of `input` is `double`, you need to use `%lf` instead of `%f` (`%f`used for `float`).

Comment: Should it be `!= EOF` or `== 1`?

Comment: @FiddlingBits, you are correct, answer updated. [scanf returns the value of the macro EOF if an input failure occurs before any conversion. Otherwise, scanf returns the number of input items assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.](http://www.rowleydownload.co.uk/arm/documentation/index.htm?http://www.rowleydownload.co.uk/arm/documentation/scanf.htm)