# Why in my c program when I use double it only puts out 0, but when I instead use float it works?

Tags: c, gcc

When I use float, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float g;
    float f;

    scanf("%f", &f);
    g = f / .5;
    printf("%f", g);
    return 0;
}
```

and enter 2 I get back 4.000. When instead in the place of `float` I use `double` the result is always 0.000. Why is this am I missing something?

Comment: _When instead in the place of float I use double the result is always 0.000._ ... because you need `scanf("%lf", &f);` for a `double`

Comment: If you possibly can, use a better compiler, or enable more warnings. A modern compiler would have told you precisely what you did wrong here.

Comment: @SteveSummit What c compilers would you suggest? I'm just starting out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double g;
    double f;

    scanf("%lf", &f);
    g = f / .5;
    printf("%lf", g);
    return 0;
}
```

You need to use the format specifier specifically for doubles (`%lf`) here.

See [format string specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string#Format_string_specifications) for more information about different format specifiers.

Comment: Thank you. I had thought I tried that but I clearly messed it up somehow.

Answer (score 1):

As, [Scanf not reading in double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33269283/scanf-not-reading-in-double),

You lied to the compiler: when scanning, `%f` says you supply a pointer to `float`. But you provided a pointer to `double`.

To fix, either use `%lf` or declare input as `float`.

Note that there is an asymmetry with `printf` formats, which uses `%f` for both `float` and `double` arguments. This works because `printf` arguments are promoted to `double` (and are not pointers).