# Variable of type double not working when read by scanf()

Tags: c, variables, double, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    double d;

    scanf("%f", &d);
    printf("%f\n\n",  d);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I get:
[error](https://youtu.be/FlsVwXLg7zk).

This code is meant to read the variable double and display it on the screen but it does only display "0.0...".

If I just change the variable type to `float` it does exactly what I want but if I make it a `double` it just reads '0'. Why?

Comment: _I'm new to programming and I searched it on the Internet and I couldn't find an answer._, We'll, you certainly did not search enough. Thought I don;t see how google failed to answer your question.

Comment: The basic problem is that when it sees a `%f`, `scanf()` expects it was given a `float *` (and given `%lf` it expects to get a `double *`), and passing a `double *` but telling it to expect a `float *` leads to unhappiness.  In some ways, the more interesting question is — Why does this work: `float f = 3.1416; double d = 2.78128; printf("%f %f\n", f, d);`?  The answer is part of the standard (it is fully defined behaviour), but is probably more subtle than you need to deal with at the moment.

Comment: Oh, and another (jocular) way of looking at the whole problem: You lied to `scanf()`, and it gets its own back by not doing what you want.  This is entirely legitimate behaviour on its part.

Comment: A comment on Jonathan Leffler's edit: C is case-sensitive, so `double` and `DOUBLE` are two unrelated names. `double` is a keyword and a type name; `DOUBLE` is just an ordinary identifier. Don't use all-caps for emphasis when discussing C keywords and identifiers. Don't even capitalize them at the beginning of a sentence.

Comment: The compilation of your code, per your link provided, reported "0 warnings".  This is key as the problem (mis-match specifier/type) _should_ have been reported.  So either 1) insure your complier warning options are fully enabled or 2) use a better compiler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanf for double not working in Dev C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657977/scanf-for-double-not-working-in-dev-c)

Answer (score 1):

In your code,

```
 scanf("%f", &d);
```

is wrong. For `scanf()`, `%f` expects a pointer to `float` as argument.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.2, *`fscanf()`*

> `a`,`e`,`f`,`g`
>
> Matches an optionally **signed floating-point number**, infinity, or NaN, whose
>   format is the same as expected for the subject sequence of the strtod
>   function. **The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to floating.**

In case you want to *scan* a `double`, you have to use

```
 scanf("%lf", &d);
```

---

FWIW, passing incompatible type of argument for any format specifier invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11`,

> [...] Unless assignment suppression was indicated by a *, the
>   result of the conversion is placed in the object pointed to by the first argument following
>   the format argument that has not already received a conversion result. **If this object
>   does not have an appropriate type, or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented
>   in the object, the behavior is undefined.**